# Asp.net c# How to update Onesignal tags on asp.net page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to Onesignal.com push notifications, I manage to add it to my asp.net site,my problem is does anyone knows if and how I can change the user tags with the Api, for register user.
One more, now I add the javascript code and when user comes to my page he can register throw the popup modal, I want to know if there is a way to register with a button click event with the api

I'll be thankful for c# code example

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to set tags on a website is to use the OneSignal Javascript SendTags method.

You can call `OneSignal.push(["sendTags", {key2: "value2", key3: "value3"}])` any time after `var OneSignal = OneSignal || [];`

To trigger the permission event from a button link, you should use the `registerForPushNotifications` method. For example (inside of the click event handler):

```
OneSignal.push(function() {
  OneSignal.registerForPushNotifications();
});`
```

Note that you should first set autoRegister to false in the `init` method.